# Migrating data from SCO OpenServer 5.0.6

Tags: database, sco, openserver

I've been tasked to migrate data from an old HP NetServer LH3000 running SCO OpenServer 5.0.6 (circa 1998).

I've had a good amount of experience dealing with Unix/Linux systems. However, this is clearly before my time as the file structure is somewhat different to what I'm used to.

The server is accessed via a Telnet connection. From what I can see, there are scripts set to run in the user profiles, which then call other scripts.

As I unfamiliar with a UNIX operating system of this age, I am not sure where to begin looking.

I would like to figure out where or how the data is being stored and if it is possible to migrate it off the server.

As I unfamiliar with a UNIX operating system of this age, I am not sure where to begin looking. Where do I start?